# Measure total execution time for multiple function calls with callback

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback

If I have code like below where method `DoWork()` is synchronous, it is easy to measure the total execution time for the `n` number of calls

```
File: PrepareForWork.cpp
    Timer startTime = GetCurrentTime();
    for (int i = 0, i < n; i++)
    {
        workerObj->DoWork();
    }
    cout << "Total execution time: " << GetCurrentTime() - startTime << endl;

File: Worker.cpp
    Worker::DoWork()
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

But in the case of asynchronous method `DoWorkAsync()` which has a callback function `CallBackOnComplete()` when the compute actually completes, how do I measure the total execution time? It seems more non-trivial as the codes are in different cpp files.

```
File: PrepareForWork.cpp
    for (int i = 0, i < n; i++)
    {
        workerObj->DoWorkAsync();
    }

File: Worker.cpp
    Worker::DoWorkAsync()
    {
        //Do something
    }

    Worker::CallBackOnComplete(Data* outputData)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Comment: If those methods on `Worker` are virtual, then your main program can just subclass `Worker` as `TimedWorker` or similar and give it a reference to a thread-safe timing routine or simply make the two methods compute and store the elapsed time which you can then retrieve afterwards.

Comment: This is where profilers can help you. The can show you in detail how much time is spent in which function. And even if you are losing time on thread synchronization (locking mutexes, waiting for I/O etc). Then there is wall time and cpu cycles etc. etc.

Comment: Could giving startTime to your workers be an option?
They can give exec time in the callback function, then the larger value being total execution time.

Comment: Is `Worker` has some `join` method? Can we inject code in `CallBackOnComplete`?